# How to Create Windows 8 Style installer

Tags: windows, wix, installation, nsis

I am looking for how to create installer similar to the one shown below:

[image: Visual Studio Installer Image]

Above is Image of Installer of Visual Studio 2013.. this installer works great on windows 7 / 8 .. I tried several options and created sample installers (including nsis, wix, inno5) but none of them provides this kind of UI for installer.

Anybody knows or created installer similar to this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio uses the [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) for its installer. The basic WiX Installer does not look like that, but using the Burn tool that is included you can create a custom bootstrapper that has a WPF user interface that mimics the one you like. There is also a very active [user mailing list](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/mailinglist/) that you can submit questions to if you need additional assistance while working on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something very similar with the predefined support from [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com). See the next sample: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/surface-screen-shot.html

Note, that this is not possible in the free edition of Advanced Installer you need at least a Professional license. However, you can test all of this in the trial period to see if it fits your requirements, during trial you can access all the features.

From what I remember installers with similar UI, created with Advanced Installer, are used by the [products of NServiceBus](http://particular.net/downloads).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the VS2013 installer is basically a wix installer but with a customized bootstrapper (burn) for the UI, which is also part of the wix toolset.